# struct member 'Initializer element is not a compile-time constant'

Tags: c, struct, initializer

```
struct S {
   int a;
};

int a = ((struct S) {8}).a;
```

the compiler reports an error "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant", why ?

Answer (score 5):

Because that struct in the brackets is actually a run-time thing. You can only assign constants to a global on initialization. e.g.

```
 int a = 8;
```

You cannot do this with globals:

```
int b = 8;
int a = b; // Because b is a run-time variable
```

Often this technique is used for defining global constants:

```
#define MY_CONSTANT 8
// Then somewhere else you can use it...
int a = MY_CONSTANT;
// or
struct S s = {MY_CONSTANT};
```

Comment: Just a note that the the declaration `int a = b` is valid in the scope of a function.  You'll only get the error if you declare the variable in file scope.